# Are those distributional solutions that are functions, the same as weak solutions?

Tags: differential-equations, generalized-functions

There are two closely related concepts and I am not sure exactly how close.  Consider a partial differential equation.  (The coefficients need not be constant but assume they are functions, and not more general distributions):

A *weak solution* is a function that satisfies the weak form of the equation.

A *distributional solution* is a distribution that satisfies the equation itself, when derivatives are understood as distributional derivatives.  (As Alexandre Eremenko remarks in a comment, this will not always make sense since you cannot always multiply distributions.  But it does make sense in the case that the distribution is a function, which is the case I ask about.)

The second concept is actually broader since, for example the Dirac delta $\delta$ is a distributional solution of the ordinary differential equation (in variable $x$) $xf'=-f$ but not a weak solution since it is not a function.

What I do not know is this:  When a function is a distributional solution to an equation then is it always a weak solution? And vice versa?

I believe I can show the answer is yes in both cases for linear partial differential equations, by fairly direct calculation.  But I fear I may be missing some nuance.  And I am not at all sure how to proceed for non-linear PDEs.

Comment: You can check that the definition of a distributional derivative is identical to that of a weak derivative. The restriction that a weak solution be a function is unnecessary for a linear PDE, if the coefficients have sufficient regularity. It is, however, often needed, for nonlinear PDEs.

Comment: @DeaneYang  No, the definitions are not the same. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative notes the Cantor function "does not have a weak derivative because its distributional derivative, namely the Cantor distribution, is a singular measure and therefore cannot be represented by a function."

Comment: A "distributional soluton" of an equation does not always make sense, since we cannot in general multiply distributions. That's the reason for defining weak solutions for each class of equations: one has to make sure that all operations involved in the equation make sense.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko  Thanks.  I edited the question.

Comment: How do you define the "weak form" of a general equation?

Comment: I think it's not really a universal convention (despite Wiki) that a "weak solution" has to be an almost-everywhere-pointwise defined function, locally in $L^1$... So the fact that the derivative of the Cantor function "is not a classical function" only becomes disruptive in more complicated situations as alluded to by @AlexandreEremenko. So the basic answer would be (I think) that "distributional solns" are often the same class as "weak solutions", but sometimes might be a strictly larger class.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, right! But it may have a sense of _denying_ linearity and smoothness of coefficients? So maybe "weak" is vague, meant to allow some actual not-classical-differentiability, but without caving in toooo far to allow arbitrary distributions? Surely conventions vary...

Comment: @ChristianRemling Good question.  Wikipedia's answer is as good as any I have seen: "one starts with a differential equation and rewrites it in such a way that no derivatives of the solution of the equation show up (the new form is called the weak formulation, and the solutions to it are called weak solutions)." But that is not very precise.  For linear equations it is straightforward to multiply by an arbitrary test function and integrate, then eliminate derivatives of the sought function. I do not know about the nonlinear case. I will wait to see what others say about this..

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: I had the same idea as a knee-jerk reaction (in a now deleted second comment). But it seems unhelpful because, as you point out, it's imprecise, and in those cases where it's clear what it means one typically seems to be back to the distributional interpretation of the equation and then your question disappears. But this last part of the comment is imprecise itself...

Comment: @paulgarrett  Yes, but when you say "sometimes," you do not mean "in some mathematical cases."   You mean "according to some people's terminology."  I have specified my terminology and while you correctly say it is not universal, it is common.

Comment: ... and then there are possibilities (already in the linear case) where either wavefront sets are disjoint and allow multiplication, or, similarly, finer gradations of "distribution" (e.g., by Sobolev or other spaces) allow a broader scope of operations. So, if I were asked what _I_ thought, it'd be to mention these possibilities, and probably not so much to mention what seems to me the needlessly vague Wiki convention, for example. So my meta-question would be about whether the question is about conventions, of whom, and with what properties, or about fulfillment of intent... ?!?

Comment: ... at the very least, I'd think there's the issue of what kind of coefficients are intended to be allowed for linear equations, whose multiplication must be legit.

Comment: ... e.g., to be silly, a product of two locally $L^1$ functions need not be locally $L^1$. So my reframing claim might be that the question needs refinement before it can be answered in a fashion that is informative ... beyond counter-example games.

Comment: @paulgarrett  Does the edit help you, when I say the coefficients must be functions and not more general distributions?

Comment: For a linear PDE with sufficient regular coefficients, the two types of solutions are essentially equivalent. For a nonlinear PDE, you have to assume enough regularity so that the integral of a test function times the nonlinear terms is well-defined. But, since you can't do nonlinear things to measures (such as squaring them), this usually forces one to assume that a weak solution is a function with sufficient regularity. For example, if the unknown function is $f$ and the PDE contains a term with $f^2$, then $f \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ is not good enough.

Comment: Aaaand, to add more turmoil: I guess there are linear and non-linear "(elliptic, etc.) regularity" results. Vaguely (!?) the solutions are ("often" [sic]) no worse than the coefficients in such cases. But without something like (hypo-) ellipticity I'd imagine that even the linear case would have many gotchas. (Interesting issue(s), for sure!)

Comment: Concerning the quoted definition of Wikipedia, in which sense does it apply to the weak form of Poisson's equation which is derived at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation? Derivatives of the solution still appear in it.