# Is there a standard definition of weak form of a nonlinear PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

Comments on the question [Are those distributional solutions that are functions, the same as weak solutions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366411/are-those-distributional-solutions-that-are-functions-the-same-as-weak-solution?noredirect=1#comment925399_366411) suggest there might not be a standard definition of the weak form of a non-linear PDE.

Is there one?

For my most specific concern: Is there a standard weak form for the Navier-Stokes equation (in the  [Millennium Prize version](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf) if that matters)?

Comment: That's correct. In general, you have to be *very* careful working with the concept of weak solutions of a nonlinear PDE.

Comment: @DeaneYang That makes sense.  But is there some reasonably standard general definition to use so that I can be careful?  Or do people create a specific version for each specific non-linear problem?

Comment: the study of nonlinear PDEs is almost always done in an ad hoc way. This is in sharp contrast to how research is done in almost every other area of modern mathematics. Although there are commonly used techniques, you usually have to customize them for each PDE, and this often includes the definitions.

Comment: @DeaneYang I think that answers this question.  Will you make it an answer?

Comment: Ok. I was hoping someone else would say more.

Comment: @DeaneYang is there a standard definition of the weak form of a _linear_ PDE? Wikipedia doesn't show one.

Comment: I don't know that I would use the word "standard", but the usual working definition is the following: If $P$ is a linear differential operator and $P^*$ its formal adjoint, then you would say that a distribution or function $u$ is a weak solution of $Pu = 0$, if for any smooth compactly supported function $v$, $$ \int uP^*v = 0. $$ A necessary condition is that the integral is well defined. This requires the coefficients of $P$ and $u$ to lie in appropriate topological vector spaces.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Wikipedia gives a routine you can easily see will work in the linear case--described succinctly by Deane Yang here - subject as he says to the coefficients being nice enough that the result is integrable. I would say it as: multiply by an arbitrary test function then integrate by parts to eliminate derivatives of the sought function.

Comment: Thanks @DeaneYang and Colin McLarty, I was not aware of that. It confuses me that many places (including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation)) call $\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \,dx = \int_\Omega f v \,dx$ the weak form of Poisson's equation $-\nabla^2 u = f$.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, thanks for that example. It shows that my working definition is not the only possible one. If the differential operator is in divergence form, e.g., $$Pu = \partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_ju),$$ then $u$ is a weak solution of $Pu = 0$ if, for any compactly supported smooth function $v$, $$ \int a^{ij}\partial_iv\partial_ju = 0. $$ This allows the coefficients to be only bounded and measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The study of nonlinear PDEs is almost always done in an ad hoc way. This is in sharp contrast to how research is done in almost every other area of modern mathematics. Although there are commonly used techniques, you usually have to customize them for each specific PDE.

Comment: To make things even worse: given a PDE there is not a unique weak solution. For example the OP seems to be concerned about Navier-Stokes: in this case there always exist weak (Leray) solutions, the 1.000.000$ prize consists in showing existence of strong solutions. But these strong solutions need not be classical (smooth), for example in presence of a non-smooth forcing term. So "strong solutions" here are actually weak solutions, but just a little bit stronger than the weakest ones.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon The link to the official problem statement from the Clay institute is in the question, and seems to me to clearly state that the prize is for proving or refuting the existence of smooth solutions for smooth initial data.

Comment: @Robert Further: I'm no specialist here, but as far as I understood the consensus is that the real challenge is to get strong solutions first. Showing that strong solutions are actually smooth is not the most difficult part (well, if the forcing is smooth, of course). But perhaps I misunderstood something here, so please don't take my word for granted.

Comment: For a concrete example of weak solutions to a nonlinear PDE, the recent resolution of the Onsager conjecture is a spectacular case. See, for example, Terry Tao's writeup: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/onsagers-conjecture/